# simple exponential smoothing ses() calculating AIC and BIC

Tags: r

Is there a code to calculate AICc and BIC in  ses() ? 
Here is my model: 
fit1 = ses(maxtemp2,initial = "simple",alpha = 0.7,h=5)

Answer (score 0):

AIC and BIC are used when comparing models whose coefficient's have been estimated using maximum likelihood (ML). ses() is a function that uses means of data, transformed or not. Akaike or BIC cant help you since the formulas inherently take into account the amount of parameters estimated by ML.

I would suggest simply testing "Goodness of Fit"

Answer (score 0):

you can also just type fit1$model to get the AIC and BIC